# PostgreSQL: row_to_json() and bytea Base64 encoded

Tags: postgresql

I’m playing with Postgre's `row_to_json()` function.

Is there is a way for changing the encoding of bytea fields/columns to Base64?

**Example**

```
SELECT row_to_json(ROW(E'\\x0102030405'::bytea))
```

Result:`{"f1":"\\x0102030405"}`

Expected: `{"f1":"AQIDBAU="}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand your question, but

```
SELECT row_to_json(ROW(encode(E'\\x0102030405','base64')));
```

will produce the result you expect.